# Как выводить разную структуру постов в одном цикле wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый, подскажите как реализовать вывод постов с разными калссами и разной структурой в одном цикле, не понимаю как это сделать.
Например:

```
          <!-- начало цикла, основная обертка -->

          <div class="module__blog__row row">

            <!-- первый вид поста --> 
            <div class="col__50 module__blog__item__content">
              <img src='' />
              <div class="module__blog__item module__blog__item_absolute">
                <span class="module__blog__date"> дата </span>
                <a class="module__blog__link" href=""> линк </a>
                <a class="module__blog__more" href=""> линк </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- обертка для других 2ух видов постов -->
            <div class="col__50">
              <div class="row">

                <!-- второй вид поста --> 
                <div class="col__50">
                  <img class="module__blog__img" />
                </div>

                <!-- третий вид поста --> 
                <div class="col__50">
                  <div class="module__blog__item module__blog__item_padding">
                    <span class="module__blog__date"> дата </span>
                    <a class="module__blog__link" href=""> линк </a>
                    <a class="module__blog__more" href=""> линк </a>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

              <!-- четвертый вид поста --> 
              <div class="module__blog__twitter">
                <p> какойто текст </p>
                <a href=""> линк </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- конец цикла, пвотор -->
```

Накидал простой пример разметки, если можно пример как это сделать.

```
обертка
<div class='wrapper'>
     первый пост
     <div class='post-view-1'>
         <div class='post'></div>
     </div>
     обертка для других постов
     <div class='post-view-wrapper'>
         второй пост
         <div class='post-view-2'>
             <div class='post-2'></div>
         </div>
         третий пост
         <div class='post-view-3'>
             <div class='post-3'></div>
         </div>
         четвертый пост из определенной категории, если это возможно реализовать
         <div class='post-view-4'>
             <div class='post-4'></div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
повтор цикла
```

Comment: Можно считать итерации и в зависимости от значения писать условие с разным кодом. Если нужно задать разную разметку не определенным по счету постам, а по другим признакам то пишите условия с ними

Comment: @РашенБеар могли бы вы на прмере моей новой разметки которую я добавил, написать свой?

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть логическая проблема здесь. Вывод будет зависеть от числа (наличия) постов разных видов.
Для примера - два случая:

Вид 1 - 10шт, Вид 2 - 1шт, Вид 3 -20шт

Вид 2 - 0шт, Вид 2 - 50шт, Вид 3 - 1 шт

В случае 1 - у вас будет пустая вторая колонка начиная со второй строки и пустая первая - с 11 строки.
Во втором - первая вообще пустая, вторая полная, третья - один пост.

Смотреться будет... Странно.
Но, если вы все-таки хотите именно это - то вам надо сделать примерно так:

1. Выборка всех видов постов и размещение данных в массивы $postsA, $postsB, $postsC и т.д.
2. Цикл по макс. кол-ву:

`for ( $i = 0; $i < max( count( $postsA ), count( $postsB ), count( $postsC ) ); $i ++ ) {
    if ( !empty( $postsA[ $i ] ) ) {
        //Тут вывод данных поста типа "а"
    } else {
        //Тут вывод заглушки, елси посты данного вида кончились
    }
    if ( !empty( $postsB[ $i ] ) ) {
        //Тут вывод данных поста типа "а"
    } else {
        //Тут вывод заглушки, елси посты данного вида кончились
    }
    if ( !empty( $postsC[ $i ] ) ) {
        //Тут вывод данных поста типа "а"
    } else {
        //Тут вывод заглушки, елси посты данного вида кончились
    }
}`

Comment: Спасибо, но получилось вот что: http://radikal.ru/lfp/s009.radikal.ru/i307/1704/31/420a6c807c4f.png/htm   цикл создает 3 разных конетйенра и кладет в них один и тот же пост потом опять осдает 3 разных конейнера и кладет в них одинаковый пост, я хотел что бы цикл в 3 разных контейнра ложит 3 поста потом следующие 3 итд, насчет разметки вы правы, реализации плиткой идет, и плитка разных размеров http://s020.radikal.ru/i717/1704/f9/cb393b49233b.png

Comment: непонятно: В случае 1 - у вас будет пустая вторая колонка начиная со второй строки и пустая первая - с 11 строки.  где? какие строки? колонка? я ничего не понял

Comment: Вам надо извлекать _данные_ постов в массив. Потому что при переборе в цикле вордпресс меняет глобальную переменную с данными поста. А вам нужно сохранить копии данных.

Кроме того, почитайте на тему query_posts() и множественных циклов в целом.

Вот тут, например https://www.howtomake.com.ua/wordpress/4-sposoba-zadat-loop-wordpress.html

Ну и вообще гуглите на тему "циклы водпресс"