# Как выводить по 3 поста в цикле wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Добрый, подскажите как выводить по 3 поста в цилке с разными классами. 
Судя по всему как сделать [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655861/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-wordpress) никто не знает либо я не понял.
Вероятно это мне поможет в решении задачи выше с разной разметкой.

```
<?php
  $query = new WP_Query();
  if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post();?>

      <div class='item_1'> post 1 </div>
      <div class='item_2'> post 2 </div>
      <div class='item_3'> post 3 </div>

      <div class='item_1'> post 4 </div>
      <div class='item_2'> post 5 </div>
      <div class='item_3'> post 6 </div>

      <div class='item_1'> post 7 </div>
      <div class='item_2'> post 8 </div>
      <div class='item_3'> post 9 </div>

    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  } ?>
```

Вероятно можно каждым третим постом выводить пост из другой категории? Я не совсем понимаю как это сделать, у меня они дублируются и каждый третий пост это первый пост из другой категории, хотя они должны увеличивать на один.

```
<?php
  $query = new WP_Query();
  if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while( $query->have_posts() ){ $query->the_post();?>

      <div class='item_1'> post 1 </div>
      <div class='item_2'> post 2 </div>
      <div class='item_3'> post 1 - другая категория if exists </div>

      <div class='item_1'> post 3 </div>
      <div class='item_2'> post 4 </div>
      <div class='item_3'> post 2 - другая категория if exists </div>

      <div class='item_1'> post 5 </div>
      <div class='item_2'> post 6 </div>
      <div class='item_3'> post 3 - другая категория if exists </div>

    <?php }
    wp_reset_postdata();
  } ?>
```

Comment: Если сделать 3 цикла, то все просто. Если делать один, придется писать множество условий.

Comment: @labris если вам не сложно можно пример того как это сделать, пусть будет три цикла, для разбора, я делал тремя и они дублируют одно  тоже.

Answer (score 1):

В одном цикле никак этого не сделать. Используйте get_posts.

```
$args1 = array( ...... );
$myposts1 = get_posts( $args1 );

$args2 = array( ...... );
$myposts2 = get_posts( $args2 );

$args3 = array( ...... );
$myposts1 = get_posts( $args3 );
```

И выводите эти три массива как хотите, обычным циклом php.